# How to sort the list according to the following logic?

Tags: python

The task is this:
I need to calculate the response time of the admin to the user's messages in the support chat.

For every message from a user, I need to find an answer from the administrator.
If a user has written more than one message in a row, the time is counted from the first message of the user to the first response of the administrator.

I pulled the necessary data from the API and formed the following list:

```
[['User', '2021-10-13 11:54:38', "message"],
['User', '2021-10-13 11:55:33', "message"],
['Admin', '2021-10-13 11:56:14', "message"],
['Admin', '2021-10-13 12:07:58', "message"],
['User', '2021-10-13 12:25:55', "message"],
['Admin', '2021-10-13 12:26:30', "message"],
['User', '2021-10-13 12:57:38', "message"],
['Admin', '2021-10-13 12:58:11', "message"],
['Admin', '2021-10-13 13:05:45', "message"],
['User', '2021-10-13 13:21:59', "message"]]
```

This array must be sorted in pairs: the first message of the user - the first message of the admin. I can't figure out how to do it

Comment: How do you identify different users? And that the response from the administrator was to a particular user?

Comment: You have to just set ascending or descending on your time format to get your expected output.

Comment: So I assume you need to follow some sort of First In First Out rule. Before the last message from the user, you have 4 user messages and 5 admin messages. How can an reply from the admin been before the user message?

Comment: @DaniMesejo this is a chat with one specific user, and only he is answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using zip to compare each message with its successor. This will let you find the indices in the list where the originator changes.   Then, using zip again, you can pair up the indices of changes where the first item in the pair is a user message.

```
messages = [
    ['User', '2021-10-13 11:54:38', "message"],
    ['User', '2021-10-13 11:55:33', "message"],
    ['Admin', '2021-10-13 11:56:14', "message"],
    ['Admin', '2021-10-13 12:07:58', "message"],
    ['User', '2021-10-13 12:25:55', "message"],
    ['Admin', '2021-10-13 12:26:30', "message"],
    ['User', '2021-10-13 12:57:38', "message"],
    ['Admin', '2021-10-13 12:58:11', "message"],
    ['Admin', '2021-10-13 13:05:45', "message"],
    ['User', '2021-10-13 13:21:59', "message"]
]

resp = [i for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(messages,messages[1:]),1) if a[0]!=b[0]]
pairs = [(messages[u],a and messages[a] or ['NoResponse','','']) 
         for u,a in zip([0]+resp,resp+[None]) if messages[u][0]=='User']

for uMsg,aMsg in pairs:
    print()
    print(uMsg)
    print(aMsg)

['User', '2021-10-13 11:54:38', 'message']
['Admin', '2021-10-13 11:56:14', 'message']

['User', '2021-10-13 12:25:55', 'message']
['Admin', '2021-10-13 12:26:30', 'message']

['User', '2021-10-13 12:57:38', 'message']
['Admin', '2021-10-13 12:58:11', 'message']

['User', '2021-10-13 13:21:59', 'message']
['NoResponse', '', '']
```

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood your question correctly, something like this?

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

entries = [
    ['User', '2021-10-13 11:54:38', "message"],
    ['User', '2021-10-13 11:55:33', "message"],
    ['Admin', '2021-10-13 11:56:14', "message"],
    ['Admin', '2021-10-13 12:07:58', "message"],
    ['User', '2021-10-13 12:25:55', "message"],
    ['Admin', '2021-10-13 12:26:30', "message"],
    ['User', '2021-10-13 12:57:38', "message"],
    ['Admin', '2021-10-13 12:58:11', "message"],
    ['Admin', '2021-10-13 13:05:45', "message"],
    ['User', '2021-10-13 13:21:59', "message"]
]

for entry in (next(group) for _, group in groupby(entries, key=itemgetter(0))):
    print(entry)
```

Output:

```
['User', '2021-10-13 11:54:38', 'message']
['Admin', '2021-10-13 11:56:14', 'message']
['User', '2021-10-13 12:25:55', 'message']
['Admin', '2021-10-13 12:26:30', 'message']
['User', '2021-10-13 12:57:38', 'message']
['Admin', '2021-10-13 12:58:11', 'message']
['User', '2021-10-13 13:21:59', 'message']
```

The way it's written now, it just iterates over a generator-expression and prints the "filtered" entries, but it's trivial to turn this into a list-comprehension instead.

Comment: You could do `next(group)` instead of `list(group)[0]`

Comment: @DaniMesejo Good idea! Avoids building an unnecessary list.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the size/complexity or scalability compared to `itertools` but here is a method for sorting by date then by title and zipping the results.

```
import datetime
sorted_by_date = sorted(unsorted_list_lists, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
user = [_ for _ in sorted_by_date if _[0] == "User"]
admin = [_ for _ in sorted_by_date if _[0] == "Admin"]
results = zip(users, admins)
```